# Are there any Windows 7 drivers available for the HP Tx2000 tablet PC?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, tablet

[Has anyone tried the new tablet features of Windows 7 on the HP TX2001au tablet](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3653674&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&softwareitem=ob-77258-1&dest_page=product&os=4062)?

[HP has Vista drivers, but no Windows 7 drivers are available yet](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&softwareitem=ob-77258-1&product=3653674&os=4062&lang=&).

The main issue I've encountered after installing Windows 7 is that the graphics card (Nvidia GeForce Go 6150) and the coprocessor are not detected.  The latest [191.07 GeForce/ION Driver][4] installer says that it cannot find any compatible hardware.

Additionally, I haven't been able to get XP running on this hardware. The Nvidia GeForce Go 6150 driver seems to be customized by HP. If you install the laptopvideo2go.com/ drivers on XP, there's a Windows warning that it can't verify the publisher of the driver, followed by a blue screen of death if you continue the installation.

Is there a way to debug the BSOD under Windows XP, or has anyone gotten Windows 7 working on this hardware?

Answer (score 1):

i had the very same problem. The solution was found on guru3d.com with their newest go6150 drivers, it did some thing with the sms and after that it found the co-processor and windows 7 ultimate 64 works alright.

Comment: is it working without crashing ? gimme the links

Answer (score 0):

http://de.download.nvidia.com/Windows/nForce/standalone/430_410/8.26_11.09_nforce_winxp_international.exe

this Nvidia driver works. but what to to with coprocessor?

Comment: whats the difference between this one and this one : http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7%5Fwinvista%5F32bit%5F191.07%5Fwhql.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the Tx2510 and I've got drivers for all my stuff. You might look at similar models, make sure its the same chipsets, and then download them from there. Or of course, windows update has a lot of them. It did take them like 3 months to get those up thought :/

Comment: where are the links for this? I only see multimedia solutions uploaded. Where are the graphics drivers?

Comment: They're on windows update for one, but at HP..under graphics on here http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3747931#N788